# Preload and defer JS and call functions therein within the HTML doc

Tags: javascript, html, preload

Suppose there's a JS file:

```
// a.js
function a(){ console.log('hello from a.js') }
```

and an HTML file where I want to **preload** and **defer** the `a.js` JS file such that I can call functions in `a.js` from within `b.html`:

```
<!-- b.html -->
<html>
<head>
  <link re='preload' as='script' href='a.js'>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<script defer src='a.js'>  <!-- calling a() below doesn't work -->
<script       src='a.js'>  <!-- calling a() below does    work -->

<script>
a()  // doesn't work with `defer`, works without `defer`
</script>
</html
```

How can I accomplish that?

One way is to wait for the page to load:

```
<script defer src='a.js'>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){ a() })  // Works
</script>
```

but this is rather inelegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not put it in head with defer? No need to preload a script you're using on the same page, also, why are your script tags outside body and head?

Comment: Putting the script in the head with defer still doesn't work.